# socketFailed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, exception

When I try to send a String to my server by WiFi catch IOException with this message: socketFailed: EACCES (Permission denied).
This is the fragment of code on I try this

```
 private void enviar (String envio){
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.1.124:36000/"+envio);
        conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conexion.setDoOutput(true);
        conexion.setRequestMethod("POST");
        DataInputStream request = new DataInputStream(conexion.getInputStream());
        conexion.connect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(SDCardImagesActivity.this, "URL erronea", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(SDCardImagesActivity.this, "Fallo de protocolo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(SDCardImagesActivity.this, (CharSequence) e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    }
}
```

And this the manifest of app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SDCardImagesActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

If somebody can help my, iI will feel grateful

Comment: ... Case sensitive...

Comment: What? Where? Where are the fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change all `ANDROID.PERMISSION` strings to `android.permission` into your manifest file: Android is case sensitive.

Comment: I can't understand, I use autocompletate

Comment: @KevinLopez: There is [a bug in the permission auto-complete in Android Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=157123). If you fix your permissions, as is shown in this answer, you should be in better shape.

Comment: I don't know, it's your IDE problem. What are you usin? I suggest Android Studio.

Comment: I change the capital letters but now when I start the app and use this method, the app be stopped. I use Android Studio

Comment: Ps: try first to solve your IDE problem as suggested by CommonsWare

Comment: I don't know the error, the app stands out without error

Comment: Are you doing the connection in the main thread? You should do all long tasks in a worker thread (also http requests). Take a look at the AsynkTask class.

Comment: I'm doing the connection in the main thread because is the principal function and not create the connexion until other process are finish, because to send, I need the other parts of my app and send the message is the last. Should, even so, do the connection in other thread?

Comment: Yes, you definitely have to put the connection task in a separate thread in any case.

Comment: Friends, I love you. you save my live, thanks for your help and your patience